If there exists $G$ that is union of disjoint bounded open intervals such that $|A\setminus G|<\epsilon$, then $A$ Lebesgue measurable?
I'm reading Axler's Measure Theory text and came across the following question. 
A note that I've read the related posts and they don't answer my specific question about weakening the hypothesis.
I've proved the forward direction and was working on the reverse direction:
If for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $G$ that is the union of finitely many disjoint bounded open intervals such that $|A\setminus G| + |G \setminus A| < \epsilon$, then $A$ is Lebesgue measurable. However, I proved it using a slightly weaker hypothesis-- I am not using anything related to $|G\setminus A|$, only $|A\setminus G|$, and wanted to check that I'm not missing a piece. In addition, I say that the $G$'s only need to be Borel subsets. Indeed, I think that:
If for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $G$ that is a bounded Borel subset such that $|A\setminus G| < \epsilon$, then $A$ is Lebesgue measurable. This is implied by the hypothesis in the question and is therefore a stronger statement.
Proof:
Let $\epsilon>0$. There exists a $G$ such that $|A\setminus G|<\epsilon/2$, by hypothesis. Also, $G$ is a Borel subset. Therefore, there exists a closed set $F\subset G$ such that $|G\setminus F|<\epsilon/2$ (Axler proved this already). Now notice that $|(A\cup G) \setminus F| = |(A\setminus G) \cup (G\setminus F)|\leq |A\setminus G| + |G\setminus F| < \epsilon/2 + \epsilon /2 = \epsilon$, where the first equality is due to $F\subset G$, and the first inequality is due to subadditivity of the outer measure. Therefore we have produced a closed set $F\subset A\cup G$ such that $|A\cup G \setminus F|<\epsilon$, meaning that $|A\cup G|$ is Lebesgue-measurable (we proved the equivalency already). Since $G$ is a Borel subset, it is also Lebesgue measurable. Therefore $A = (A\cup G) \setminus G$ is Lebesgue measurable, due to this property of sigma algebras.
So we have shown that $A$ is Lebesgue measurable. Note that we only used the weaker statement that $|A\setminus G|<\epsilon$, not anything to do with $|G\setminus A|$. I'm also only relying on the fact that $G$ is a bounded Borel subset, not necessarily the union of finitely many disjoint bounded intervals. Is this not needed in the backwards direction?
Thank you!
Cole

The statement that you claim to prove is not true. The error in your proof is that the equation
$$
A = (A\cup G) \setminus G
$$
need not hold (for example, consider the case where $A = G$).

I see that now—whoops!
Thanks a lot for the comment and your books- loved LADR!
